# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'DateAdapter' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Issue:

When I run `ng serve` the Angular/Typescript project compiles correctly. However the Angular Material UI is not being displayed. The structure of the project is the following:

```
---src
    |-----index.html
    |----- app
            |----- app-routing.module.ts
            |----- app.component.html
            |----- app.component.scss
            |----- app.component.ts
            |----- app.module.ts
            |----- material-module.ts
```

Inside app.component.ts I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

However, when I include `<app-root></app-root>` tag inside index.html I am unable to see the html which I put inside app.component.html. In browser, however, when I inspect with the developer tools I run into the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'DateAdapter' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021:1)
    at compiler.js:10583:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10558:1)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:10493:1)
    at compiler.js:10580:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10558:1)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:23876:1)
    at push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857:1)
```

Goal: Display Angular Material UI code on a localhost server

Comment: Can you provide code? It sounds like material-module.ts has an error in the code.